# workaround for GWT+Jetty JSP compiler issue? (Java 1.5 source level not recognized)

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, gwt

As [this thread](http://groups.google.com/group/Google-Web-Toolkit/browse_thread/thread/ae8728724c2bf71/e975705066ee6f2c?lnk=gst&q=Syntax+error%2C+%27for+each%27+statements+are+only+available+if+source+level+is+1.5#e975705066ee6f2c) shows, there seems to be an issue getting JSPs to compile in GWT hosted mode with the new Jetty server:

```
2. ERROR in /tmp/Jetty_0_0_0_0_8080_war____ut4fm1/jsp/org/apache/jsp/ 
test_jsp.java (at line 53) 
        new java.util.ArrayList<String>(); 
                                ^^^^^^ 
Syntax error, parameterized types are only available if source level 
is 1.5
```

Does anyone have a workaround?  It's possible that [this commit](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/detail?r=5109) might be related.  I don't know what equivalent to `org.eclipse.jdt.core.JDTCompilerAdapter` should be used for  building outside of Eclipse (e.g. on the command line).  This is a real blocker for us adopting GWT 1.6, so any pointers are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This problem is generated by the default values used by JspServlet, which compiles using 1.4 for source/target values.

1. You can cofigure this servlet by adding

   ```
   <servlet>
       <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
       <servlet-class>org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet</servlet-class>
       <init-param>
           <param-name>compilerSourceVM</param-name>
           <param-value>1.5</param-value>
       </init-param>
       <init-param>
           <param-name>compilerTargetVM</param-name>
           <param-value>1.5</param-value>
       </init-param>
       <load-on-startup>3</load-on-startup>
   </servlet>
   ```
2. There is one more issue as you can't configure JspServlet with the current jasper-compiler-5.0.28. You should download [jasper-compiler-5.0.30](https://raisercostin.googlecode.com/svn/maven2/tomcat/jasper-compiler/5.0.30/jasper-compiler-5.0.30.jar) and make sure is in your classpath before gwt. There are other latest jasper compiler jars out-there but i'm not sore of how compatible are with jakarta-tomcat-5.0.28.
   <del>I solved this problem by adding a dependency on jakarta-tomcat-5.0.30 in GWT 1.6.4. You can download the GWT compiled with this dependency from http://raisercostin.googlecode.com/files/gwt-windows-1.6.4.raisercostin.zip</del>

I described the solution at  http://code.google.com/p/raisercostin/wiki/GwtEclipsePluginDebug too.