# Adding a JSP file to a GWT project in Eclipse Helios( and Galileo )

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, jsp, gwt, jetty

I have a GWT project in Eclipse to which i try to add a jsp file. I run the application in development mode and when i try to access that jsp file i get the following error:

> HTTP ERROR 404
>
> Problem accessing /testing.jsp.
>   Reason:
>
> ```
> /testing.jsp
> ```
>
> Powered by Jetty://

I'm using Eclipse 3.6 (tried it on 3.5 too with the same results), GWT 2.1 and GAE 1.3.8

Comment: It probably has something to do with [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/807317/workaround-for-gwtjetty-jsp-compiler-issue-java-1-5-source-level-not-recognize): The JSP compiler in the embedded Jetty defaults to Java 1.4 source - so if you have Java 5 sources, they won't compile. Unfortunately, the solution provided in the answer to the mentioned question is only for GWT 1.6. It doesn't work (for me) on GWT 2.1 - maybe someone has an updated solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's strange - it works out of the box on my machine:

- GWT 2.1
- GPE (Google Plugin for Eclipse) 1.4.0
- Eclipse 3.6

I just do the following:

- Create a new Google Web Application (from Eclipse).
- Add a "testing.jsp" directly in the "war" directory *(not for example in "war/myApp/")*
- Start development mode ("Run as Web Application").
- Go to http://127.0.0.1:8888/testing.jsp?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997 *(exactly this URL)*

<sub>[The only case when it doesn't work for me is, if I use Java 1.5 code in the jsp file. But then I get a 500 error, not a 404.]</sub>

Can you try this exact scenario, and see, if it works?

Comment: I did exactly like you said and now it works. I think the file wasn't in the right folder after all. It was in the project folder instead the war folder. I think i assumed it was in the right place because  eclipse says there's an error in the jsp file when the file is in the war folder, even tough there aren't any errors (i just used the file generated by eclipse without adding anything to it). When i run the app i get an error but i ignore it and everything goes well. Thank you for your help Chris!

Answer (score 1):

A 404 error means it can't find the file.  Your jsp file should go in the war directory, not in your source tree: project/war/testing.jsp

Comment: That's not the problem, the file is in the right folder. Thanks

Comment: Do you have any URL filters set up in your web.xml file, or other redirection that would stop it from finding your jsp file?  I think this is definitely not a compiler issue.

Comment: +1 You're right, a compiler problem would result in a 500 http error. @Lucian: Did you also make sure, that uppercase/lowercase of the filename is correct?

Comment: @Chris: Yes, i was very careful. Tried it on different machines too. I lost hope, i'm using IntelliJ now